# Triggering form's submit event doesn't execute event handler

Tags: javascript

If I have the following event handler bound to my `form`:

```
form.addEventListener('submit', function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  console.log('submitted');
  this.submit();
});
```

When the form is submitted by the client, the event handler is executed and **the form is submitted without the event handler being executed again**.

However, the same logic doesn't apply when attaching `click` handlers to `anchor` elements:

```
a.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  console.log('clicked');
  this.click();
});
```

The event handler is executed twice and the link is never followed.

I have two questions:

- Why does it appear to work differently for `submit` vs `click`?
- Why does the anchor's `click` handler only get executed twice and not indefinitely, if the event handler is being executed each time it's called?

Comment: In a simple test I made, the submit is executed indefinite times. May there's an error in `this.click()`

Comment: @StavNoy By the standard the submit event must not fire when submitted by the submit method of the form ([item 6 in the submit algorithm](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#form-submission-algorithm)). If you're using ex. jQuery's submit method, then the submit listener will be fired.

Comment: @Teemu not with the `evt.preventDefault()`. 
Here's an example where it works: https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-c55t7j?file=index.html

Comment: @StavNoy Your code snippet doesn't use the submit method of the form.

Comment: `addEventListener('submit')` ? Unless you mean `form.onsubmit = ...` or `<form onsubmit="..."`, but the question uses `addEventListener` (and my guess is they're all the same in this case)

Comment: Ah, I finally noticed the event handler is a `function`, not an arrow, and saw `this` _is_ the form, and with `this.submit()` the form is submitted normally, so the submission algorithm does take place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form submission and element click are different actions, they don't have to behave in the same way.

When using the submit method of the form, [the standard says](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-form-element:dom-form-submit):

> Submits the form, bypassing interactive constraint validation and without firing a submit event.

This can be seen also in [the submission algorithm](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#form-submission-algorithm). Item 6 checks, whether the action comes from the submit method of the form, and skips the validation and event firing if the "*submit()*" flag is set.

[`element.click`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#dom-click-dev) sets "*click in progress flag*", which is checked internally before creating a syntehtic click event which calls the hander function. This prevents a click on an element to lead to infinite recursive click event handler calls.